# How to convert csv to json after checking condition

Tags: python, json, csv

I need to convert csv to json.

- If `|` has to convert to `,`
- if flag is Y or N then it has to add to same value

csv is below

```
value,name,flag
ABC,ab@gmail.com|cd@gmail.com,Y
ABC,de@gmail.com,Y
CDE,ab@gmail.com,N
CDE,cd@gmail.com,N
```

My code is below

```
import json
import csv
json_data = []
for row in csv.DictReader(open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\a.csv')):
   row['name'] = [row['name'].replace('|', ',')]
   json_data.append(row)
json.loads(json.dumps(json_data))
```

My output is below

```
[{'value': 'ABC', 'name': ['ab@gmail.com,cd@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'Y'},
 {'value': 'ABC', 'name': ['de@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'Y'},
 {'value': 'CDE', 'name': ['ab@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'N'},
 {'value': 'CDE', 'name': ['cd@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'N'}]
```

Expected out

```
[{'value': 'ABC', 'name': ['ab@gmail.com,cd@gmail.com','de@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'Y'},
 {'value': 'CDE', 'name': ['ab@gmail.com','cd@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'N'}]
```

Can we do using`DictReader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach could be the following. In each iteration you can check the existing keys on a dictionary (or JSON, would work on both), and while you go row per row, you can check if already exists, and from that take the decisions with if/else. However, for getting this solution working, I removed the column names from the CSV file.

```
import csv, json
aux = [] # our json
values = [i["value"] for i in aux] # check all existing values
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    CSVfile = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for line in CSVfile:
        if line[0] not in values:
            aux.append({
            "value": line[0],
            "name": line[1].split("|"),
            "flag": line[2].replace("\n", "") # included in the CSV
            })
        else:
            idx = values.index(line[0]) # where is?
            for to_append in line[1].split("|"):
                aux[idx]["name"].append(to_append)
        values = [i["value"] for i in aux] # update in each iteration
# save the file json.dump...
with open("file.JSON", "w") as f:
    json.dump(aux, f)
```

Comment: can we do using DictReader

Comment: @sim I updated the code to use the csv library, not the DictReader method, I don't know if that meet your requirements